# Proper configuration of CORS to stop PDFs from opening in Web browser

Tags: pdf, cross-browser, aem, content-disposition

My server has links to other servers. I have a relationship with the managers of those servers. I want to be sure that links to PDF files make the client Browser prompt the user to SAVE the file, not to have the file open directly in the Web browser. I don't believe I need to change the HTTP Headers on my server, I need to ask the admins on the associated servers to change THEIR HTTP headers to "allow cross origin" when they receive requests from my site as the "referrer". Is this correct? It's not easy to get this answer, lots of examples to this type of query talk about "go to your Browser settings and change how PDFs are handled", but I need a solution that, apart from users who HAVE set their Browser as their OS default PDF viewer, the PDF files will download to be opened in a sophisticated and powerful PDF renderer.

Tried some experiments on two servers I have direct control over, it seemed to work, but now need to engage with other server admins and I want to be sure I'm asking them to alter their HTTP config header without bothering them excessively: I don't want to have to do a lot of "experiments" with them, I want to be confident that what I'm asking them to do or change is correct.

Comment: This has got nothing to do with CORS, but everything to do with [`Content-Disposition`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Disposition).

Comment: add a header `Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="filename.pdf"` to response.

Comment: Are the PDFs hosted in AEM or dynamically generated via a back-end service? In any case, this has to do with Content-disposition headers, set up at the Apache level if the files are hosted in a Web server or adding it to the response from a servlet if via Java or any other back-end.

Comment: Thanks: any physical PDF files (static, not generated) are stored in my local server, so they are "same origin" everything works as desired: PDFs do not open in the Browser, the user is prompted to save the file then they can open it in Adobe Reader or whatever... the AEM links we're trying to support going forward are DYNAMICALLY generated: we want a "PDF Datastream" that comes straight from AEM's memory, not a "file download" also to be forced to save, not open in the browser... the Cross-Origin aspect seems to be involved, but also the Content-Disposition is being investigated. Thanks all.